# Is it possible to log the server IP address by using log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j2

I have `log4j2.properties` file which is used for the application log. Now by using that properties file I need to print the hostname/ip address to the output log file. I do not want to modify application code(java class) for this.

Comment: For printing client IP address, it can be dong using `Thread Context Map (MDC)` however, you have to write one filter in your web application which should put client IP address in thread context.

Comment: It means we need to put server ip address programatically. Is it possible to fetch the ip address dynamically without changing any class in the application.

Comment: you need to log server ip address or client ip address  and your application is web application ?

Comment: Yes it is a web application.

Comment: Need to print server's host name/IP address for web application

Comment: So why does your title and your question say 'remote (client) IP address'?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print server host name in your web application, then include `${hostName}` in your layout pattern.

For `log4j2 properties configuration`, below pattern should print hostname of the server -

```
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${hostName} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg%n
```

Comment: Client ip address also required to identify from where the request came.

Comment: @SubhajitPal first decide which IP address you want to print in logs - client or server ? In above comments, you said you want server IP address

Comment: FYI, client IP address can not be printed without writing some code

Comment: I understand that server ip can be shown by using hostName in the log pattern. But for client ip it is required to modify code. Is it possible to package it with the log4j configuration, library and the java code to fetch the client ip as jar and use that jar for logging information in the application. If yes how could I do that?